# Select only calculated columns in Propel

Tags: php, propel, propel2

I'm trying to perform a selection with Propel which returns only calculated columns, but I allways have other columns selected.

For example:

```php
$criteria = new MuestraQuery();
$criteria->clearSelectColumns()
    ->addAsColumn('numEspesores', 'count(distinct muestra.sal_espesor)')
```

Resulting query:

```sql
 SELECT muestra.sal_id, muestra.sal_regimen, 
        -- ...
        -- (ALL FIELDS OF THE TABLE HERE...)
        -- ...
        count(distinct muestra.sal_espesor) AS numEspesores 
 FROM muestra
```

I've been able to reduce the number of fields selected including only a field. For example, this query returns only two fields:

```php
$criteria = new MuestraQuery();
$criteria->clearSelectColumns()
    ->select(MuestraTableMap::COL_SAL_ID)
    ->addAsColumn('numEspesores', 'count(distinct muestra.sal_espesor)')
```

Resulting query:

```sql
SELECT count(distinct muestra.sal_espesor) AS numEspesores,
       muestra.sal_id AS "muestra.sal_id" 
FROM muestra
```

¿Is there a way in Propel to select only computed columns?

I've seen columns are added in `ModelCriteria->doSelect()` based on protected `ModelCriteria->isSelfSelected` property, which is set in `ModelCriteria->select()` but not in `addAsColumn()` because it's from Criteria and it's not overriden in ModelCriteria.

Don't know if this is a bug or I'm doing something badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the computed column that you added.

```
MuestraQuery::create()
    ->select(['numEspesores'])
    ->addAsColumn('numEspesores', 'count(distinct muestra.sal_espesor)')
    ->find();
```

Due to Propel's fluent api, you do not have to call the `select` method prior to the `addAsColumn` method, so you could even do the following:

```
MuestraQuery::create()
    ->addAsColumn('numEspesores', 'count(distinct muestra.sal_espesor)')
    ->select(['numEsesores'])
    ->find();
```